# How to detect duplicate keys in hash and add prefix to the duplicate?

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays and I am creating a key-value-pair using hash in Ruby. How can I detect a duplicate key when zipping two arrays into key-value-pair and adding a prefix like "A-" in front of the key name for the duplicates?

I am using .zip to merge two arrays and making one a key and other one a value

```
[0] = "David"
[1] = "John"
[2] = "Alex"
[3] = "Sam"
[4] = "Caleb"
[5] = "David"
[6] = "John"
[7] = "Alex"
[8] = "Sam"

[0] = "1"
[1] = "2"
[2] = "3"
[3] = "4"
[4] = "5"
[5] = "6"
[6] = "7"
[7] = "8"
[8] = "9"


name_number_key_value_pair_hash = first_names.zip(numbers).to_h
puts(name_number_key_value_pair_hash)
```

Expected:
`{"David"=>"1", "John"=>"2", "Alex"=>"3", "Sam"=>"4", "Caleb"=>"5", "A-David"=>"6", "A-John"=>"7", "A-Alex"=>"8", "A-Sam"=>"9"}`
Actual: 
`{"David"=>"6", "John"=>"7", "Alex"=>"8", "Sam"=>"9", "Caleb"=>"5"}`

Comment: Please show the arrays in your example as valid Ruby objects, in part so that readers can cut-and-paste: `arr1 =  ["David", "John", "Alex", "Sam", "Caleb", "David", "John", "Alex", "Sam"]` and `arr2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]`. By setting a variable equal to each array, as I've done, readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems straight forward Have attached code snippet

```
names = %w[David John Alex Sam Caleb David John Alex Sam]
numbers = %w[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] 

key_pair = {}
names.each_with_index do |name, index|
  name = "A-#{name}" if key_pair[name]
  key_pair[name] = numbers[index]
end
```

It generates the expected output:

```
{"David"=>"1", "John"=>"2", "Alex"=>"3", "Sam"=>"4", "Caleb"=>"5", "A-David"=>"6", "A-John"=>"7", "A-Alex"=>"8", "A-Sam"=>"9"}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks Rahul

Comment: What you have written returns `names`, not the desired hash. You need to add a final line, `key_pair` (which would be essential if your code were to be wrapped in a method). That may be obvious to most of us, but possibly not to readers new to Ruby. To avoid that, use `names.each_with_index.with_object({}) do |(name, index),key_pair|`. Also, as a matter of general practice, I suggest writing `if key_pair.key?(name)` (or `has_key?`), rather than `if key_pair[name]`, both because it reads better and because it's a good habit to get into for times when `nil` is a valid hash value.

Comment: result = names.zip(numbers).reduce({}) { |memo, (names, numbers)| memo.merge(memo.key?(names) ? "A-#{names}" : names => numbers) }

Answer (score 0):

You basically just need to keep track of the state of the hash as you build it and, when you find a conflict, create a new key instead. This captures the general approach:

```
def hash_with_prefixes(a, b, prefixes)
    kv_pairs = a.zip(b)
    prefixes = prefixes.to_enum
    result_hash = {}

    kv_pairs.each do |initial_key, value|
        final_key = initial_key

        while result_hash.include? final_key
            final_key = "#{pfx.next}-#{initial_key}"
        end

        prefixes.rewind
        result_hash[final_key] = value
    end

    result_hash
rescue StopIteration
    fail "Insufficient prefixes to provide unique keys for input lists."
end
```

At the *slight* expense of clarity, you can also write it in a rather shorter form:

```
def hash_with_prefixes(a, b, prefixes)
    pi = Hash[a.map {|k| [k, prefixes.lazy.map {|p| "#{p}-#{k}"}]}] 
    a.zip(b).inject({}) {|h, kv| h[h.include?(kv[0]) ? pi[kv[0]].next : kv[0]] = kv[1]; h}
rescue StopIteration
    fail "Insufficient prefixes to provide unique keys for input lists."
end
```

(Don't do this.)

Answer (score 0):

This is really very simple.

```rb
names = ["John","John", "John", "David", "David", "Susan", "Sue"]
numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6","7"]

def uniq_hash_keys(names, numbers)
  hash = {}
  names.each_with_index do |name,i|
    if hash[name]
      prefix = 'A1-'
      key = prefix + name 
      while hash[key]
        version = prefix.match(/A(\d+)-.*/i)[1].to_i
        prefix = "A#{version + 1}-"
        key = prefix + name 
      end 
      name = key 
    end 
    hash[name] = numbers[i] 
  end 
  hash 
end
```

This function produces:

```rb
{
  "John"=>"1", 
  "A1-John"=>"2",
  "A2-John"=>"3",
  "David"=>"4",
  "A1-David"=>"5",
  "Susan"=>"6",
  "Sue"=>"7"
}
```

Notice that there are 3 Johns, this is why the while loop is inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Using `zip` and `each_with_object`

```
names   = %w[David John Alex Sam Caleb David John Alex Sam]
numbers = %w[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] 

names.zip(numbers).each_with_object({}) do |(name, number), hash|
  key          = hash.key?(name) ? "A-#{name}" : name
  hash[key]    = number 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to create the desired hash. Note that in `arr1` "John" appears three times.

```
arr1 = ["David", "John", "Alex", "Sam", "Caleb",
        "David", "John", "Alex", "John", "Sam"]
arr2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]

prefixes =
  arr1.each_with_object({}) do |s,h|
    if h.key?(s)
      prefix = "A-"
      (h[s].size-1).times { prefix = prefix.next } 
      h[s] << prefix
    else
      h[s] = ['']
    end
  end 
    #=> {"David"=>["", "A-"], "John"=>["", "A-", "B-"],
    #    "Alex"=>["", "A-"], "Sam"=>["", "A-"],
    #    "Caleb"=>[""]} 

arr1.map { |s| "#{prefixes[s].shift}#{s}" }.zip(arr2).to_h
  #=> {"David"=>"1", "John"=>"2", "Alex"=>"3", "Sam"=>"4",
  #    "Caleb"=>"5", "A-David"=>"6", "A-John"=>"7",
  #    "A-Alex"=>"8", "B-John"=>"9", "A-Sam"=>"10"}
```

Note that `"A-".next #=> "B-"` and `"Z-".next #=> "AA-"`.

**Alternative data structure**

You may wish to consider a different data structure, one that returns

```
{"David"=>["1", "6"], "John"=>["2", "7", "9"],
 "Alex" =>["3", "8"], "Sam" =>["4", "10"], "Caleb"=>["5"]}
```

You could do that as follows.

```
arr1.each_with_index.
     group_by(&:first).
     transform_values { |v| arr2.values_at(*v.map(&:last)) }
  #=> {"David"=>["1", "6"], "John"=>["2", "7", "9"],
  #    "Alex" =>["3", "8"], "Sam" =>["4", "10"],
  #    "Caleb"=>["5"]}
```

See [Enumerable#each_with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index), [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), [Hash#transform_values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values)<sup>1</sup> and [Array#values_at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-values_at). `v.map(*:last)` is here the same as `v.map { |arr| arr.last }`.
The steps are as follows.

```
a = arr1.each_with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["David", "John", "Alex", "Sam",
  #     "Caleb", "David", "John", "Alex", "John", "Sam"]:
  #     each_with_index>
```

We can see the values that will be generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array.

```
a.to_a
  #=> [["David", 0], ["John", 1], ["Alex", 2], ["Sam", 3],
  #    ["Caleb", 4], ["David", 5], ["John", 6], ["Alex", 7],
  #    ["John", 8], ["Sam", 9]]
```

Continuing,

```
b = a.group_by(&:first)
  #=> {"David"=>[["David", 0], ["David", 5]],
  #    "John"=> [["John",  1], ["John",  6], ["John", 8]],
  #    "Alex"=> [["Alex",  2], ["Alex",  7]],
  #    "Sam"=>  [["Sam",   3], ["Sam",   9]],
  #    "Caleb"=>[["Caleb", 4]]} 
b.transform_values { |v| arr2.values_at(*v.map(&:last)) }
  #=> {"David"=>["1", "6"], "John"=>["2", "7", "9"],
  #    "Alex"=> ["3", "8"], "Sam"=> ["4", "10"], "Caleb"=>["5"]}
```

For the last step, the first value of the hash `b` is passed to the block and the block variable is assigned to that value.

```
v = b.values.first
  #=> [["David", 0], ["David", 5]]
```

The block calculations are then as follows.

```
c = v.map(&:last)
  #=> [0, 5] 
arr2.values_at(*c)
  #=> arr2.values_at(0, 5)
  #=> ["1", "6"]
```

The calculations are similar for each of the remaining values of `b` that are passed to the block.

<sup>1. New in Ruby MRI v2.4.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This code is less readable but compact and functional-style.

It conceptually the same as rahul mishra code https://stackoverflow.com/a/54697573/2109121

```
names = %w[David John Alex Sam Caleb David John Alex Sam]
numbers = %w[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

result = names.zip(numbers).reduce({}) { |a, (b, c)| a.merge(a.key?(b) ? "A-#{b}" : b => c) }
```